# Empty uploaded file in Symfony with unknown User Agent

Tags: php, symfony, user-agent

I am using Symfony for a collection of REST APIs and I keep getting an exception of an **empty uploaded file**. It happens about 5-10 times every day in an application which has about 5000 users per day.

This is the relevant code:

```
$receipt = $request->files->get('receipt');

if (!$receipt || !($receipt instanceof UploadedFile) || !$receipt->isValid()) {
    throw new \Exception('No uploaded receipt image. Maybe the image is too large?');
}
```

I already increased the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to a very high value but the error still occurrs. I noticed that the **user agent** is always "strange":

```
User-Agent: myappname/104 CFNetwork/808.0.2 Darwin/16.0.0
```

Where `myappname` is the name of my mobile app (only the last part, without com.mycompany.myappname). Could it be an emulator or a hacking attempt?

Answer (score 0):

If upload_max_filesize is larger than post_max_size then increase post_max_size then it will be bigger that upload_max_size and if the value of post_max_size is more than memory_limit, then to increase memory_limit then it will be larger that post_max_size.
If still happening then try to restrict you REST APIs with ip or domain if your frontend and backend are on separate domain
user "Nelmio CORS" setting

```
# Nelmio CORS
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_origin:  ["%cors_allow_origin%"]
        allow_methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        allow_headers: ["content-type", "authorization"]
        max_age:       3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

by using composer install nelmio/cors-bundle
or similar.